# Query variable value and set a conditional statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an mySQL database for a 3rdparty application. One of the tables in this database is called Users.

There is a field in this table called USR_Role

I would like to query the Role field and if the user is a member of a particular role then set @@manager==1 else @@manager==0

Here is my current code:

```
$user = userInfo(@@USER_LOGGED);
$user1 = $user['Role'];

if ($user1 == 'AMA_NoTravelApproval'){
    @@Manager==1;}
else
{@@Manager==0;}
```

I know very little PHP at this stage but when debugging within the application I do not get an error so unsure if the code has an error or the application is not applying it.

Comment: I've never seen the double @@ symbol used in PHP.  What are you using it for?  A single @ symbol is used to suppress errors, so you may be suppressing errors you should be seeing.  Also, the double == symbol is used to compare values, not set values.  A single = is used to set a value. (So your line `@@Manager==1` is comparing it to 1, not setting it to 1)

Comment: what is @@USER_LOGGED?

Comment: @SgtAJ The @@ is usually used to indicate variables within the application. In previous times I have had to use PHP for this application the $ is the PHP variable and the @@ has been used to pull data stored within the Application.

A sample of past code used to auto populate fields within the application is:
@@data = userInfo(@@USER_LOGGED);
@@Traveller_Name = @@data['firstname'] . ' ' . @@data['lastname'];
@@Traveller_Email =  @@data['mail'];
@@travel_contactphone = @@data['phone'];
@@starteruser = @@USER_LOGGED;

So how do I set a value not compare?